# Hankel determinants related to Motzkin paths

Tags: combinatorics, determinant

Let $M_{n,k}(t,s)$ denote the weight of all Motzkin paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,k)$ where the weight of a horizontal step at height 0 is $s,$  the weight of a horizontal step at height $k\geq 1$ is $t$ and the weight of up-steps and down-steps is $1.$ The weight of the path is the product of the weight of the steps.
Computations suggest that $\det_{0\leq {i,j}\leq {n-1}}\left(M_{i+j,k}(t,s)\right)=\det_{0\leq {i,j}\leq {n-1}}\left(M_{i+j,k}(t-s,0)\right).$
Is there a combinatorial reason for this fact?

Comment: The **weight** of a Motzkin path as defined [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0002200.pdf) (page 6) is the **product** of the individual weights. Do you endorse this definition (which isn't evident) or do you take the sum of the weights ? Besides, do you have a reference about these matrices ? (I found this reference in the following document "Motzkin paths, Motzkin polynomials
and recurrence relations" (Roy Oste and Joris Van der Jeugt) available on the web.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my post.

Comment: A nice presentation of weighted Motzkin paths [here](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~kratt/vortrag/cigldet.pdf) and associated Hankel determinants (begin at dia 42).